# VBA TextToColumns Errors Relating to Date Format

Tags: excel, vba, date-conversion

I am having a problem with date formatting and TextToColumns.  Although similar to some other threads, I couldn't match them directly to my problem.

Background:  I have a recurring relatively large *.csv file that includes three columns of date/time stamps.  These are currently text in the form 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm'.  My computer is D/M/Y by default.  If I manually use the Text To Columns feature in Excel (delimited, no delimiters selected, column data format Date: DMY), then the conversion occurs correctly.

Error: In trying to automate the conversion in VBA, I recorded a macro as a starting point and then went from there.  Once I completed writing the routine, I ran it and saw that it only did about half the dates.  Further investigation revealed that it only changed dates that could be either way... i.e. the day did not exceed the 12th.  I then realised what was happening was that the code only 'worked' when it could interpret the date in a MDY format.  This means that it actually created an error as dates such as 05/02/2010 (5 Feb 2010) then appeared as 02/05/2010 (2 May 2010).

The key part of the code is as follows:

```
Range("SCDB").Columns(aryColTitleIndex(i)).TextToColumns _
  Destination:=Range("SCDB").Columns(aryColTitleIndex(i)), _
  DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
  ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
  Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, xlDMYFormat), _
  TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

(The named ranges and column indexes are working fine).  I tried FieldInfo:=Array(1, 4) as well as what is shown above, but no change.  Basically, it looks like VBA wants to operate in MYD but Excel in DMY.

Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: Use "Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=strInPath, Format:=xlDelimited, Local:=True" when opening the CSV file and it should be fine.

Comment: Actually, the ***key part of the code*** will be the line that opens the file. That is where the magic needs to be done. If you have Excel 2010+, you might be better off using `Power Query` aka `Get & Transform` in 2016+ to do the import and conversion.  You can record a macro while doing that, also. Upload and post a link to a specimen CSV file so we can test things out.

Comment: Thanks Michal, doesn't work for me as hoped though.  In my post I mentioned the file is *CSV, what I should have said it that it is a report created as a *CSV but it is already loaded in as *xlsx by the time I get it.  I'm pretty sure that is why what you recommended trying doesn't work for me in this instance.  Also, I am in Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

The "best" way to handle this will be to properly import the CSV file.  If you do that, you can specify the date format at the time of import, before Excel converts the dates into a combination of text strings, and improperly converted dates.

If that is not possible, and must absolutely work with the xls file that has incorrectly imported the original data, you can try this macro. It should work, but read the notes carefully for possible pitfalls and usage information.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ConvertDates()
    'converts dates that have been mismatched MDY / DMY
    'Assumes dates are all in selected column
    '   Only need to select a single cell in the column
    '   will place results in a column next to original data
    ' If adjacent column is not blank, a column will be inserted
    'Figures out the original format by analyzing a "text" date
    'Time components are converted directly.  This might be OK unless
    ' in a non standard format such as 1400Z

Dim R As Range, C As Range
Dim sDelim As String
Dim FileDateFormat As String * 3
Dim I As Long, J As Long, V As Variant
Dim vDateParts As Variant
Dim YR As Long, MN As Long, DY As Long
Dim TM As Double
Dim vRes As Variant 'to hold the results of conversion

Set R = Selection

'Test that selected cell contains a date
If Not IsDate(R(1)) Then
    MsgBox "Select a cell containing a date"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set R = Intersect(R.EntireColumn, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
ReDim vRes(1 To R.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)

'Find a "text date" cell to analyze
For Each C In R
    With C
    If IsDate(.Value) And Not IsNumeric(.Value2) Then
        'find delimiter
        For I = 1 To Len(.Text)
            If Not Mid(.Text, I, 1) Like "#" Then
                sDelim = Mid(.Text, I, 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next I

        'split off any times
        V = Split(.Text & " 00:00")
        vDateParts = Split(V(0), sDelim)

        If vDateParts(0) > 12 Then
            FileDateFormat = "DMY"
            Exit For
        ElseIf vDateParts(1) > 12 Then
            FileDateFormat = "MDY"
            Exit For
        Else
            MsgBox "cannot analyze data"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    End With
Next C

If sDelim = "" Then
   MsgBox "cannot find problem"
   Exit Sub
End If

'Check that analyzed date format different from Windows Regional Settings
Select Case Application.International(xlDateOrder)
    Case 0 'MDY
        If FileDateFormat = "MDY" Then
            MsgBox "File Date Format and Windows Regional Settings match" & vbLf _
                & "Look for problem elsewhere"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Case 1 'DMY
        If FileDateFormat = "DMY" Then
            MsgBox "File Date Format and Windows Regional Settings match" & vbLf _
                & "Look for problem elsewhere"
            Exit Sub
        End If
End Select

'Process dates
'Could shorten this segment but probably more understandable this way
J = 0
Select Case FileDateFormat
    Case "DMY"
        For Each C In R
        With C
            If IsDate(.Value) And IsNumeric(.Value2) Then
            'Reverse the day and the month
                YR = Year(.Value2)
                MN = Day(.Value2)
                DY = Month(.Value2)
                TM = .Value2 - Int(.Value2)
            ElseIf IsDate(.Value) And Not IsNumeric(.Value2) Then
                V = Split(.Text & " 00:00") 'remove the time
                vDateParts = Split(V(0), sDelim)
                YR = vDateParts(2)
                MN = vDateParts(1)
                DY = vDateParts(0)
                TM = TimeValue(V(1))
            Else
                YR = 0
            End If

            J = J + 1
            If YR = 0 Then
                vRes(J, 1) = C.Value
            Else
                vRes(J, 1) = DateSerial(YR, MN, DY) + TM
            End If
        End With
        Next C
    Case "MDY"
        For Each C In R
        With C
            If IsDate(.Value) And IsNumeric(.Value2) Then
            'Reverse the day and the month
                YR = Year(.Value2)
                MN = Day(.Value2)
                DY = Month(.Value2)
                TM = .Value2 - Int(.Value2)
            ElseIf IsDate(.Value) And Not IsNumeric(.Value2) Then
                V = Split(.Text & " 00:00") 'remove the time
                vDateParts = Split(V(0), sDelim)
                YR = vDateParts(2)
                MN = vDateParts(0)
                DY = vDateParts(1)
                TM = TimeValue(V(1))
            Else
                YR = 0
            End If

            J = J + 1
            If YR = 0 Then
                vRes(J, 1) = C.Value
            Else
                vRes(J, 1) = DateSerial(YR, MN, DY) + TM
            End If
        End With
        Next C
End Select

With R.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn
    Set C = .Find(what:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas)
    If Not C Is Nothing Then .EntireColumn.Insert
End With

R.Offset(0, 1).Value = vRes

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll try roll that in soon.